# Property Binding on Animated Property vs Multiple Animations

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qtquick2

Consider this example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        property bool active: true
        opacity: active ? 1 : 0
        height: 300 * opacity
        width: 300 * opacity
        Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: parent.active = false }
        color: 'cornflowerblue'
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        property bool active: true
        x: 305
        opacity: active ? 1 : 0
        height: active ? 300 : 0
        width: active ? 300 : 0
        Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        Behavior on width { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: parent.active = false }
        color: 'steelblue'
    }
}
```

I have two `Rectangle`s with the same observable behavior: when clicked, they fade both in opacity and size.

Internally, it differs in the amount of `Animation`s, that are running concurrently - either 1 or 3:
[image: 1 or 3 animations]

As of now, I mainly use the pattern form `rect1` and only in cases where the bindings would get unneccessarily complex `rect2`. However I wonder, if the animation system has some magic, that optimizes the animation of a single property, while the binding might be less performant.

In which usecases it is beneficial to use pattern `rect1` and when it would be wiser to use the method of `rect2`?

**EDIT** There is also a third option which moves, what possible, to the render thread via `OpacityAnimator`. Now I can't bind to the opacity anymore, as it will jump to 0 at the end of the animation.

```
Rectangle {
        id: rect3
        property bool active: true
        opacity: active ? 1 : 0
        height: active ? 300 : 0
        x: 610
        width: height
        Behavior on opacity { OpacityAnimator { duration: 1000 } }
        Behavior on height { NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } }
        MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: parent.active = false }
        color: 'dodgerblue'
    }
```

**EDIT 2** To adress the Answer of *Ansh Kumar*:
[image]
This is an excerpt from the `QML Profiler`. You can see, that during the animation of `rect2` there are neither bindings nor JavaScript running, unlike during the times where `height` and `width` are *(efficiently)* bound to the `opacity` in `rect1` or the `width` is *(efficiently)* bound to the `height` in `rect3`.

Further the source of the animations shows little trace of `JS`. I couldn't examine it into all it's depths, but it seems, that only a `ScriptAction` gets a `QQMLScriptString` and the rest has only the cost of converting the input from `var` to the right type (if a type is specified by using a concrete animation such as `NumberAnimation`).
Further, as far as I can see, there is not a loop per animation involved, but all animations feature some kind of `update()`-function or so, that is called (when running/registered) by a single loop (`AnimationTimer`). But this is where I am already unsure about.

Now the question remains: Is the implementation of the animations more efficient than the *optimized JS environment* especially as multiple objects are created and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of bindings in QML: optimized and non-optimized bindings. It is a good idea to keep binding expressions as simple as possible, since the QML engine makes use of an optimized binding expression evaluator which can evaluate simple binding expressions without needing to switch into a full JavaScript execution environment. These optimized bindings are evaluated far more efficiently than more complex (non-optimized) bindings. The basic requirement for optimization of bindings is that *the type information of every symbol accessed must be known at compile time*.

Bindings are quickest when they know the type of objects and properties they are working with. Animating a property will cause any bindings which reference that property to be re-evaluated. Usually, this is what is desired. The `opacity`, `height` and `width` in `rect2` are re-evaluated into a full JavaScript execution environment whereas in `rect1`; `width` and `height` goes through an optimized binding expression evaluator and optimized to give more efficient binding since their type of object is known at compile time. Check [binding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#bindings) and also [animations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#animations) for more details.

**EDIT**

You were right about evaluation being done in C++ environment. I found following informations.

Rendering engine should achieve a consistent 60 frames-per-second refresh rate. 60 FPS means that there is approximately 16 milliseconds (exactly 16.6667 milliseconds) between each frame in which processing can be done, which includes the processing required to upload the draw primitives to the graphics hardware. [This](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/12/02/velvet-and-the-qml-scene-graph/) shows that the animation is in sync with the vertical refresh, so once every 16.66 ms, and exactly once pr frame.

```
while (animationIsRunning) {
    processEvents();
    advanceAnimations();
    paintQMLScene();
    swapAndBlockForNextVSync();
}
```

So, in `rect1` you have set `duration: 1000` and binded `height` with `opacity` (`height: 300 * opacity`) similarly `width` with `opacity`, so binding should be called around 60 times ? If you see `QML profiler` output of `statistics` you will find following

[image: binding1]

As expected number of calls are around 60 (exactly 63). Now if you change duration to 2000, number of calls will be doubled.

[image: binding2]

Since, `300 * opacity` has to be calculated, so `QML` should call JavaScript environment around 60 times (when `duration: 1000`)

[image: java]

As expected it was called around 60 times.

What about the `NumberAnimation`, is it implemented in JavaScript or C++ ? Definitely, you were right about it being implemented in C++, [Here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/util/qquickanimation_p.h.html#QQuickNumberAnimation) is the link to its declaration . So, in `rect1` we have used `NumberAnimation` one time and in `rect2` we have used it 3 times. So, total of 4 instances of `NumberAnimation` should be created.

[image: create]

So, `rect1` has a total of around 120 bindings and JavaScript calls whereas in in `rect2` there is no binding and JavaScript calls, so animation of `rect2` should be faster, but the question is, will there be any significant improvements? Since, free version of QtCreator does not comes with CPU analyzer I was not able to study that part of the question ([CPU Usage Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cpu-usage-analyzer.html)). If anyone has commercial version of Qt, please update me about my hypothesis. I really think that `rect2` is the best for usage as number of calls are reduced.

Comment: Why are `height` and `width` are re-evaluated in a full JS environment? I declare no intermediate variable, do not access a `var`, am not calling any JS function, have no closures or functions beeing constructed, avoid all usage of properties outside the immediate evaluation scope nor am I issuing side effects. So this should run in the *optimized mode* afaik.

Comment: @derM because  `Behavior on` will that for you even if you are not explicitly doing anything.

Comment: But there I use the specialized `NumberAnimation` which provides a more efficient implementation. So I think it should run the property-changes in a optimized C++-environment. That is why I assume, that the `NumberAnimation` might be more efficient than the more general optimized binding.

Comment: So basically the question is: What is more optimized: The *more efficient implementation of an animation:* `NumberAnimation` or the *optimized* `binding`

Comment: @derM Okay, let me take it simple. You want to animate `height` for which you are using `NumberAnimation` for a duration of `1000` ms. How do you think the `height` property is changed? It's changed by running a loop in javascript environment. So when you have 3 `NumerAnimation`s you have 3 loops, as is the case with `rect2` but in `rect1` you just have 1 loop and 2 dependents so `height`and `width` in `rect1` are optimized because there type is known at compile time.

Comment: How I think the `height` property is changed? In C++ using the [optimized C++ implementation](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/util/qquickanimation.cpp) of a `NumberAnimation`. I could not really follow this class in depth, because there are too many objects involved. But as far as I can see, there are not multiple loops involved, but a `AnimationController` registers the `Animation` to one `AnimationTimer`. I don't know the source of the latter, but I doubt, that there are multiple instances of this.

Comment: @derM I have updated my answer with more research done.